# Customize the Boot Camp Drive Icon in Lion

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, icon

A while ago, I remember having customized the Boot Camp drive icon with a pretty simple hack.

It was on Mac OS X Tiger.
And it was [that hack](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20061115060922447).

Now I'm running Lion. Windows 7 is comfy on his Boot Camp partition, and i'm willing to get some candy finish for my Mac OS' desktop icons.

The problem is: I can't find any way to do it in Lion. Google has been of no help. The hack above isn't working anymore. (It wasn't working in leopard or snow leopard neither, as far as I remember)

Magical solution needed, anyone has a clue about it?

Does OS X Lion discard completely the use of non-writable drive icons?

Answer (score 2):

<del>Will [Candybar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) work for you? It allows you to change icons, but I'm not sure about drive icons. Lemme know if it works for you.</del>

Ok, according to [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071106134344315), you can:

- Paste your icon (in the Get Info window) onto a USB thumb drive formatted as FAT32.
- The name of the drive doesn't matter.
- Launch Windows through Boot Camp, Parallels Desktop, or VMware Fusion.
- Open the thumb drive in Windows.
- Select Folder Options… from the Tools menu, and set it to show invisible files.
- Copy the two files .VolumeIcon.icns and ._[cr]File, where [cr] is a carriage return, to the NTFS drive.

According to the article, that'll work.

Comment: Yes, Candybar does indeed allow to change drive icons. I own a copy of it for a while now. But as the Boot Camp volume is NTFS formatted, you can't write to it. So you can't change the icon from Mac OS X.

Comment: FYI: I just tried this method with a Boot Camp disk on a 2019 Mac Pro running macOS 10.15 (Catalina), but after rebooting back into macOS, the icon is still the generic internal hard drive icon. : ( Oh well!